# VM Error when starting local JBoss server

Tags: java, jboss, jvm

I am getting the following error when trying to run JBoss server on my computer:

**Error occurred during initialization of VM
Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M**

I am using Windows 7. 
When I looked it up I saw that the problem is with the Java parameters setting. I have tried to set it to **-Xms512m -Xmx1024m** but it did not work (Not sure if I did it correctly).

Comment: Looks like those aren't the values used when starting your JBoss server. Check at the logs to see which parameters are being sent.

Comment: Try `JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m -Xmx512m`

Comment: Are those JBoss server parameters or System(Windows) parameters?

Comment: JBoss server parameters.

Comment: In my standalone.conf.bat file I set it to:
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128m -Xmx512m"

It is still not working

Answer (score 1):

OK I managed to work it out so I am writing the answer here for those who struggle with the same problem. The JBoss server take the parameters from the System Variables and after setting them there it worked just fine.

Thanks for your help guys.